# Spark DataFrame contains specific integer value in column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple Spark DataFrame with column `ID` with integer values `1`, `2`, etc.:

```
+---+-------+
| ID| Tags  |
+---+-------+
|  1| apple |
|  2| kiwi  |
|  3| pear  |
+---+-------+
```

I want to check if value like `2` is in the column `ID` in any row, `filter` method  is only useful for string columns. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I was trying with:
`df.filter(df.ID).contains(2)`

At the end I need `boolean` `True` or `False` output.

Comment: Please share the code with the `filter` expression you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `Filter` can filter other data types also.

```
dataDictionary = [
    (1,"APPLE"),
    (2,"KIWI"),
    (3,"PEAR")
    ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=dataDictionary, schema = ["ID","Tags"])
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
df.filter("ID==2").rdd.isEmpty()  #Will return Boolean.
```

[image]

Comment: Which tool did you use that gave you this screen capture?

Comment: 'Snipping tool' software

Comment: How to get boolean -> True / False at the end?

Comment: @JimTodd I'm referring to the spark output. Is it a notebook and if so what type?

Comment: @ggordon Yeah, I used a databricks notebook. You can achieve the same in Jupyter notebook as well.

Comment: ```'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isempty'```

Comment: Yeah, its an rdd function. Please see my updated answer above.